# How to observe adding child GameObject and get it with using UniRx?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unirx

First, please see my code.

```cs
using UniRx;
using UniRx.Triggers;
....... 
        var parent = new GameObject("parent");
        parent.OnTransformChildrenChangedAsObservable()
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                Debug.Log("child object is added");
            });
        var child = new GameObject("child");
        child.transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
```

When I set child's parent, OnTransformChildrenChangedAsObservable() is certainly called. However, I don't know how to get added object because the argument "_" is Unit, not a GameObject.
Here's what I actually want to do.

```cs
        parent.OnTransformChildrenChangedAsObservable()
            .Subscribe(g =>
            {
                Debug.Log(g.name);
            });
```

Is there a any way to realize this? In fact I'm not particular about whether UniRx is used or not.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now, it seems to be solved.
First I prepared a function as GameObject's Extension, to get its own children objects, like:

```cs
        public static List<GameObject> GetChildrenObjects(this GameObject gameObject)
        {
            var childrenObjects = new List<GameObject>();
            foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform)
            {
                childrenObjects.Add(child.gameObject);
            }
            return childrenObjects;
        }
```

So now I can get child object that added last as follows.

```cs
        parent.OnTransformChildrenChangedAsObservable()
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                var added = parent.GetChildrenObjects().Last();
            });
```